# Is it possible to request multiple nodes in one request using Services?

Tags: 7, services, entities

I would like to be able to make one request to the Services module node resource and have it return more than one node in the response. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the index crud operation on resources tab. After that you should get all the entities that are accessible to your authenticated request. I had to use hook_entity_info_alter and custom access callback to provide everyones entities of specific type for my api role user.

Comment: I am looking to retrieve the entire node objects, not just what is available in the index.